# Does OnCreate() method affects Misc time in Android Profiling?

Tags: android, performance, oncreate

Android developer page documented that  onDraw() affects draw time,  onMeasure() and onLayout() affects measure time.
But onCreate() time takes more time among the other functions.  Does this method call affects Miscellaneous time in GPU profiling?

Note: In Developers page it is mentioned that, the Miscellaneous time is the time taken for additional set of work that occurs on the main thread other than rendering system.